# How can I show error message from API to the end-user?

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript, spring-boot

I'm trying to show error message from a REST API when the user attempts to upload a file that is not an image.

The JSON returned from the API is similar to this:

```
{
    "publicError": "Could not be uploaded, it is not an image!",
    "innerError": "WrongImageTypeException()"
}
```

But i don't know how it display to the user.

I tried

```
this.setState({ errorMesage: { ...err } })
```

And the console log looks like this [image: Console log][https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/4/f642ed4326147b3f2c6899e78d415771-full.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWRcn.png).

How can I show this response error message?

## Backend code

```
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(
    @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws UserNotFoundException {

        try {
            if(!(fileStorageService.checkFileType(file))){
                throw new WrongImageTypeException();

            }
        }catch (WrongImageTypeException error){
            return ResponseEntity.status(403).body(new ErrorMessageManager(
                "Could not be uploaded, it is not an image!",error.toString()));
        }
```

## Frontend code

```
this.state : {
      errorMesage: {
        publicError: "",
      }, } 

public uploadHandler() {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.set('file', this.state.avatar);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('tk879n')}`
      }
    };
    axios.post(
      `${serverUrl}/uploadFile`,
      formdata,
      config
    ).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        userProfile: {
          ...this.state.userProfile,
          avatarUrl: response.data,
        }
      });
    }
    ).catch((err) => {

      // i want to set error message state and display in render function
      this.setState({ errorMesage: { ...err } }); 

      console.debug(this.state.errorMesage);

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.debug(this.state.errorMesage);`  shows the structure of the object:

[image]

From the structure you can see that the `this.state.errorMesage.response.data` contains the structure you are looking for:

```
"publicError": "Could not be uploaded, it is not an image!",
"innerError": "WrongImageTypeException()"
```

## Fix

So instead of `...err` you should be using `...err.response.data`